# how do i get the location of a touch in cocoa/objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am looking to get the location of a touch, preferably corresponding to the pixels of the screen. I'm new to objective-c and cocoa and haven't been able to find anything on the web about this so i'm not sure if there is even a way to do it. any ideas or direction of where to look would be really helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On iPhone you make a subclass of the UIView and implement the funktion -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(NSEvent *)anEvent:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   UITouch *myTouch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex: 0];
   CGPoint currentPos = [myTouch locationInView: self];
   NSLog(@"Point in myView: (%f,%f)", currentPos.x, currentPos.y);
}
```

Comment: awesome, but can you explain how i make a subview of UIView and where exactly i should put the code in my project file(s)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he meant "make a sub*class* of the UIView" there.

Comment: just put it in your viewcontroller.m

Comment: Sorry, being a bit tired last night. Of course I meant subclass of the UIView, not subview. Thanks for pointing that out...